# geocoding Google Maps & ASP

Tags: google-maps, asp-classic, geocoding

I'm trying to get coordinates of address from google map with Classic Asp.

When I write this address in address bar I get correct result:

`http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?output=xml&q=32822%20USA`

But I get Code 602 (bad location from google) when I try to call same address with MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp

the asp codes:

```
url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?output=xml&q=" & Server.URLEncode("32822 USA")
set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
xmlhttp.open "GET", url, false
xmlhttp.send ""
xml = xmlhttp.responseText
set xmlhttp = nothing
```

Comment: does anybody think I need to maybe try setting a User-Agent header? maybe Google thinks the script is a bot?

Comment: Works here, got the following: 
32822 USA 200 geocode
Orlando, FL 32822, USA
USUSAFLOrlando32822 -81.2760848,28.5129308,0

Comment: was that with the ASP or the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is not the URL, which is correctly formed, but the fact that you cannot do cross-domain XMLHttpRequest. Your request to the Google Maps Geocoding Service must be done from a server, that will fetch the XML content and return it to you ASP script.

Here's what I would do: your ASP script might call a PHP file that queries Google Geocoding and fetches the response with cURL and returns it to the ASP that can then process it.

---

If you don't want to use this solution, you might as well look at the Google Maps Javascript API that also provides Geocoding methods ([link](http://code.google.com/intl/it/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Geocoding))